# android sdk build tools cannot be found

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

flutter in vs code gives me "Could not locate aapt. Please ensure you have the Android buildtools installed.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_arm64.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one."
Although my build tools are up to date.

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor`?

Answer (score 0):

Going into the folder where the android sdk is located and under the 'build-tools' delete everything inside it, then using android studio re install the build tools this will fix the issue